# Defeating the "multiple methods named 'xxx:' found" error

Tags: objective-c, xcode, warnings

In my current project inside the file ViewController.m, I am running the method:

```
[[connection writer] writeData: data];
```

It returns the warning:

```
warning: multiple methods named 'writeData:' found
```

I am attempting to call the method:

```
- (void) writeData: (NSData*)data
```

...in TCPWriter.m. Unfortunately, there are two other `writeData` methods

```
- (void)writeData:(NSData *)data;
```

...in NSFileHandle.h and...

```
- (BOOL)writeData:(NSData *)data
```

...in NSURLHandle.h.  This is especially confusing to me because `[conn writer]` should return the `TCPWriter` class and that class should call the correct `writeData` method.  Furthermore, I am not even completely sure that NSFileHandle.h and NSURLHandle.h are even included in any of the libraries included in ViewController.h, rather than in a different part of the project.

How can I show the compiler which `writeData` method I want to call and why does this error happen?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Make sure [connection writer] is actually returning a TCPWriter*.  If it is returning an id, then the compiler will not know which writeData to use.  Also, make sure you are importing the TCPWriter.h file - if the compiler does not see the header files, it will default to returning id, which will get you back to the same problem.

Try

```
TCPWriter* writer = [connection writer];
[writer writeData: data];
```

or

```
[(TCPWriter*)[connection writer] writeData: data];
```

Comment: I didn't realize that it defaulted to returning an id when the file wasn't explicitly imported.  Thanks!

Comment: Turn on warnings and you will not have to wonder.  Other linker flags: -Wall, and turn on as many others, including Treat Warnings as Errors.

Answer (score 6):

As an alternative to the splendid answer above, you can cast the object to the right type to get rid of the warning too, like so:

```
[(NSView*)textView setAutoresizingMask:(NSViewWidthSizable | NSViewHeightSizable)]; // for horizontal scrolling
```