# Multiple methods named 'tag' found with mismatched result

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have added `GDataframework` in my project ,after adding it,i am getting error
"Multiple methods named 'tag' found with mismatched result". If i remove `GDataFramework` than it works fine.Can i modify in `GDataframework` or should i have to done in my project ?

```
int buttonTag=[sender tag]  //here that error prompts up at every place in my project
```

Comment: I think int buttonTag = [[sender tag] intValue]; may solve your problem. This problem occurs when method with "same name" returns "same type of value" (means if both methods return (id)).

Comment: or you can use int buttonTag = [(int)sender tag];

Answer (score 17):

Is your code inside an action method, like this?

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    int buttonTag = [sender tag];
}
```

Then you can solve the problem by replacing `id` with the correct type of the sender (`UIButton *` in this case):

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    int buttonTag = [sender tag];
}
```

because the compiler then knows that `sender` is an instance of the `UIButton` class, and therefore knows which `tag` method is applied here.

Note that you can define the correct type already when creating the connection in Xcode:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This link has a problem similar to yours: [Defeating the "multiple methods named 'xxx:' found" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038171/defeating-the-multiple-methods-named-xxx-found-error) Try to follow the guidelines the answer to this question does in your own app.

Answer (score 0):

In one scenario, if the factory method that creates the object has return type "id" then the compiler will check the method signature in all the classes. If compiler find the same method signature in more than one class then it will raise the issue. So replace the return type "id" with "specific class name".