# Not able to integrate latest ZXingObjC library in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, zxing

I am working on a barcode scanner app and would like to integrate [ZXingObjC](https://github.com/TheLevelUp/ZXingObjC) library to my app because [ZXing](https://github.com/TheLevelUp/ZXingObjC) is the only free library that supports data matrix scanning. I have gone through its [README](https://github.com/TheLevelUp/ZXingObjC/commit/425768d9582a8ce4c6ccb4da0cf1d1489637f8a1) file and tried to integrate the library. But its giving some weird errors like "*Multiple methods named “encode” found with mismatched result, parameter type or attributes*".

So I thought may be those are ARC problems and tried to convert it to ARC but no luck. It is throwing so many errors!!

I am still struggling with integrating this library. It will be really helpful if anyone can help me on this.

Comment: The easiest way if you want no headaches is to use cocoapods. ZXing is already podspeced. http://cocoapods.org/?q=zxing

Comment: Yes but README says you can simply use this by dragging the ZXingObjC folder onto Xcode. Make sure "Copy items" is checked before clicking "Add". and import the header file thats it.

Comment: What do you import when you get that error ( filename )? What is your file extension for the class that you import ZXing headers to?

Comment: I am just importing #import "ZXingObjC.h"

Comment: Show me the code in that file.

Comment: What? You should download the library and try to build a demo than you will get an idea.

Comment: It works for me. I'm not asking this for nothing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54911/discussion-between-daniel-and-ajay).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason stands behind this answer:[Defeating the "multiple methods named 'xxx:' found" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038171/defeating-the-multiple-methods-named-xxx-found-error).

Please have a look and try casting objects before calling those methods accordingly.